# Explanation about inheritance and abstract classes

Tags: java

```
public class A3 extends A2{
    public void m1() 
    {
        System.out.println("Yellow");   
    }
    public void m2() 
    {
        System.out.println("Pink"); 
    }
    public void m3() 
    {
        System.out.println("Red");  
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(" inside main ");
        A2 tp = new A3();
        tp.m1();
        tp.m2();
        tp.m3();
    }

}
abstract class A2 extends A1
{
    public void m1() 
    {
        System.out.println("Cyan"); 
    }
    public void m2() 
    {
        System.out.println("Blue"); 
    }
    public abstract void m3();
}

abstract class A1
{
    public abstract void m1();
    public void m2() 
    {
        System.out.println("Green");    
    }

}
```

Output of the above code:
inside main 
Yellow
Pink
Red

Can somebody please explain why it would print Yellow, Pink and Red and not Cyan Green Red! 
Why wouldn't the code go to abstract class for code execution?
Is override working in this code?
What should be done if you want the parent-methods to get called?

Comment: Please read about inheritance and [method overriding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would explain it.

The *compiler* will first check if a method call is *legal*. To do that, it checks the declared type of the reference variable calling the method
(no matter the type of the actual object it refers to). 
The method call will be legal if the method is defined in the declared type of the reference variable (including inherited methods). 
In your example, *the declared type of the reference variable tp is A2*. Methods m1, m2 and m3 are defined in A2. So *tp.m1();*,  *tp.m2()*, and *tp.m3();* are legal methods calls for the compiler, no matter that *tp actually refers to an A3 object*.

Then at runtime, the *JVM will check the actual object that the reference variable refers to* and apply the method implemention found in the actual object, if any. If the jvm doesn't find any implementation of the method in the actual object, it will apply the method implementation found in the declared type of the reference variable(including inherited methods). 
In your example, tp (even declared as of type A2), actualy refers to an object of type A3(which is legal since A3 extends A2).So the jvm will execute the implementations found in class A3 when calling methods m1, m2 and m3. 
If you hadn't redefined(overriden) method m2 in class A3, then the output would 've been :

```
inside main
Yellow
Blue
Red
```

Comment: Owe you buddy for such a fantastic explanation!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you don't **extend** methods but `Override` them, if you want the parent-methods to get called you need to call them yourself in the method with `super.m1()`

Answer (score 1):

Because unlike C++, in Java all instance methods are virtual.